# sqlite iphone connectivity check

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Is there any method available for checking the sqlite DB connectivity without calling

```
sqlite3_open([writableDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK
```

everytime. We end up in database connection error after 120 continuous clicks.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call sqlite3_open just once. Then, if open operation was successful, store the database handle somewhere globally (i.e., in a class variable) and then just use that handle everytime you need to make a call to the database.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot for your response. 
What if i loose the DB connectivity in between? what is the probability that i have the connectivity remain opened all the time?
please help

Comment: How do you expect to lose DB connectivity with a iPhone SQLite database?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. So can i confirm that there is no possibility for an app loose the DB connectivity anytime? if this true,I would do what you say... thanks

Comment: Matthew is right. It's almost impossible to loose DB connectivity with an iPhone SQLite database.

Comment: Yes you are right, it works fine for me here now.
Thanks a lot for your kind responses. 
Good day to you all.

Answer (score 2):

First, every [sqlite3_open](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) must be matched with a [sqlite3_close](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) before open is called with a pointer to that handle again.  Otherwise you will have resource leaks, which I think you're experiencing.

Second, why are you repeatedly opening it to begin with?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot for the response. I am opening everytime and closing the DB in the end of fetch. So its like opening and closing only but in a very fast way.
am i in the right path?